# linking facebook sdk to android project

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

After creating my android project in eclipse and importing facebook sdk, i go to properties of my android application select android and add facebook sdk and click on okay. then when i again go to properties it shows red cross mark against that facebook sdk. shown picture below too:

[image]

why ?

Edited :
My path location of files were:
My FacebookSDK is at A:\Workspace\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b\facebook and my android project application at
B:\USC\Academic\Web Tech\HWs\no9\IMDB_Scrapper

Moving Facebook sdk to same drive removed that red cross thing but gives new error as indicated below :
ya done that.but am getting a new error now. precisely this http://msu-footprints.org/2011/Aditya/sanp1.jpg

Which android support v4 library should i remove ?

Comment: your `android project` and `facebookSDk` is on same drive partition?

Comment: My FacebookSDK is at A:\Workspace\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.b\facebook and my android project application at
B:\USC\Academic\Web Tech\HWs\no9\IMDB_Scrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your android project and Facebook library on Same drive lets say `A:`

and then import it again. Now you can able to add the facebook library without error.

Comment: ya done that.but am getting a new error now. precisely this http://msu-footprints.org/2011/Aditya/sanp1.jpg

Comment: Which android library should i remove ?

Comment: I guess you have two `jars` for the support packages. remove one.