# Facebook SDK library disabling

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-java-sdk

I've added the [Facebook SDK for for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/) project to my workspace, but when I try to add it as a library to my project it keeps getting disabled. When I add it (by "Properties -> Android -> Library") it gets a green checkmark, but when I press apply/OK and return, it turned into a red cross..

I also added it at "Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries" as an external [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file.

Comment: Do you have added support v4 jar in build path?

Comment: Yes. In "Porperties-> Java Build Path -> libraries -> Android Dependencies" there is an "android-support-v4.jar"

Comment: found the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654095/linking-facebook-sdk-to-android-project